# Hide a div if it does not have one of several classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of links:

```
<ul>
   <li><a class="selection" href="appels">Appels</a></li>
   <li><a class="selection" href="bananas">Bananas</a></li>
   <li><a class="selection" href="pineapples">Pineapples</a></li>
</ul>
```

Beneath it I have several  boxes with the general term "fruits" and one or more specific fruits as its classes:

```
<div class="fruits bananas apples pineapples"></div>  
<div class="fruits bananas"></div>
<div class="fruits pineapples apples"></div>
```

My goal: When I click on a link, then all the boxes which **do not** have the selected fruit contained in their class-attribute shall hide. When the document loads, by default all div-boxes will be displayed.

Here is the jQuery I have come up with so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var element_just_clicked;
    var href_of_element;

    jQuery('.selection').click(function() { 

                event.preventDefault();                             
                element_just_clicked = jQuery(this);                    
                href_of_element = element_just_clicked.attr('href');


                // ... and now???
    });
```

Comment: Take a look at the `:not()` selector. `$(":not(.bananas)").hide()`

Comment: Should we overlook that apples is misspelled in your links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
$('.selection').click(function(e) {
  $('.fruits').show().not('.' + this.getAttribute('href')).hide();
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4qDn2/). One important note here: you have to prevent links to be processed as, well, links - hence <del>`return false`</del> (kudos to @cookiemonster for reminding me about event propagation) `e.preventDefault()` call.

I'd suggest using some `data` attribute to record this relationship - in my practice, `data-target` is often the suitable name. For example:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="apples">Appels</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="bananas">Bananas</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="pineapples">Pineapples</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$('a[data-target]').click(function() {
  $('.fruits').show().not('.' + this.dataset.target).hide();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6CXs4/). One has to swap `this.dataset.target` for `this.getAttribute('data-target')` when dealing with browsers that don't support Dataset API - unfortunately, all IE but IE11 fall into this category.

Comment: I think you'll need the attribute `href` instead of the property. The property usually gives a fully qualified URL.

Comment: @cookiemonster Argh, yes! Thank you. ) BTW, I'd rather use either data attribute or `rel` for defining these relationships.

Comment: I agree, unless perhaps the `href` is meant to be followed for non-JS-enabled browsers. Even then, a separate attribute isn't a bad idea.

Comment: @raina77ow your answer is great, thank you, i tried it out and it works. next question: how do I achieve that the space that a hidden div leaves is getting removed? I have three div boxes per line and if for example only div box #3 is being hidden with your function, then box #4 does not automatically move up to the position where box #3 was...

Comment: Thank you, for that to answer we need to see the HTML structure and CSS styling of those - at least some concept illustrating what you have. And it's better expressed as a separate question, I suppose. )

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you have to prevent the default action of those anchors, as they will redirect.
Then, you have to get the href attribute (**not** the property), and use that for the classname, and then it's just filtering and showing and hiding.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.selection').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var elems = $('.' + this.getAttribute('href')).show();
        $('.fruits').not(elems).hide();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/9pJ9Y/)

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` was a good idea since it doesn't stop the event from bubbling. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".selection").click(function() { 
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $("div.fruits").hide().filter("." + href).show();
    return false;
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uyLeZ/